# Why make command is failing here

Tags: makefile, build, compiler-errors, gnu-make, gnu

I am compiling and building my project using GNU make version 3.81. The make command was successful in building my project. However, from today, I am getting a strange error while running make. I am not sure what got changed inadvertently in my machine which is causing it to fail --

```
C:\TestView710\bora>make.exe MY_PROD
bash.exe: warning: could not create /tmp!
bash.exe: warning: could not create /tmp!
bash.exe: warning: could not create /tmp!
C:/TestView710/sysimg-ufa/bora/make2284-1.sh: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make.exe: *** [ufa-standalone-msm] Error 2
```

I have a couple of questions --

1. does `make.exe` internally invoke `bash.exe`?
2. And why is `bash.exe` complaining about `tmp` folder?
3. Also it looks like `make.exe` is creating a transient file `make2284-1.sh` which gets deleted very soon.
4. Finally how to debug and fix this problem ?

Curious to understand what is going on here.

Comment: Totally stuck here, any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Comment: As you don't show your Makefile it will be very difficult to help you.